# Allow regex or other method to format mm/yyyy date format while user types on text input field

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to formulate a javascript on a text input field to help user format MM/YYYY while filling out a form in real time. Must work in all browsers include IE11+. Can include just numbers so they don't have to type the '/'.

I'm trying regex, but probably date formatting is better option?

- So if user types: 112002 as they are typing, it should type 11/2002.
- If user types ab12000, it would ignore the ab,
  and start 12/ , then ignore the 000 after that until they type valid
  date input, which would be a valid 4 digit year.

So far what I have for the onChange event:

```
function(field, event, opts ){                
            
            var s = new String(field.value());
            if(s != null && s != '')
            {
                
                if(s.length>3) // better conditional statement?
                {
                        s = s.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''); // need more/different validation criteria here for date
                        if(s.length>2) // better conditional statement?
                        {
                             s = [s.slice(0,2),'/',s.slice(2,6)].join('');
                        }   


//something here to set the value ?

               
                }
               
            }
            }
```

Comment: Something like `(\d{2})\D*(\d{4})` perhaps?

Comment: have you considered using `<input type="date">`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date